# cannot assert a nested method call with jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular5, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write unit test for my angular5 web-application using jasmine.

The code is splitted into 3 files, namely `utilityFile.ts`, `component.ts` and `component.spec.ts`

utilityFile.ts:

```
export class UtilityFile{
     constructor(){}
     parse(){
         // do somthing
     }
}
```

component.ts:

```
export class Component{
    uf = new UtilityFile();
    constructor(){}
    runParse(){
        uf.parse(); // <-- trying to test if this method has been called
    }
}
```

component.spec.ts:

```
describe('test runParse()',()=>{
    let comp:Component;
    beforeAll(()=>{
        comp = new Compnent();
        comp.runParse();
    })
    it('should call uf.parse()', ()=>{
        spyOn(comp.uf, 'parse');
        expect(comp.uf.parse).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <-- test fails
    })
})
```

related packages:

```
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
```

I am thankful for every hint.

Comment: You never call `comp.runParse`. Also, you should really be using Angular's DI (dependency injection) to provide `UtilityFile` to `Component` and the `TestBed` to test it (see https://angular.io/guide/testing).

Comment: Thank you for the tip about `comp.runParse`. I do perform this call in the in my real code. On the other hand, I tried it with dependency injection. It didn't work. by debuggin the instance of the component I found that parse function is not directly under `comp.uf` but rather under `comp.uf.__proto__.parser`. any ideas?

Comment: Then give a proper [mcve] illustrating the actual problem. There are obvious typos in what you've posted, so it's hard to tell what the real issue is.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe. while I am preparing the proper code, I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the `describe` block.

I had to create the `spy` and **only then** I had call the function. Whereas in my question I call the function and afterward I create the `spy` and assert it.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `spy` to `beforeAll` block, where you call `runParse()`. Because `runParse()` calls `uf.parse()` first and at that time there was no `spy` created to watch out for. So `spy` should be created before it is called.

```
describe('test runParse()',()=>{
    let comp:Component;
    beforeAll(()=>{
        comp = new Compnent();
        spyOn(comp.uf, 'parse');   // create spy before calling runParse()
        comp.runParse();
    })
    it('should call uf.parse()', ()=>{
        expect(comp.uf.parse).toHaveBeenCalled(); // should pass now
    })
})
```